# Filter ODATA Model in sapui5 and bind with tilecontainer

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I"m binding my tile container in xml view as

```
    <TileContainer id="idsolutionContainer"     tiles="{ path: 'dlCourses>/DLES_COURSE_CONTENT' }">
       <tiles>
            <dles:DLESScoreTile name="{dlCourses>LJ_TITLE}" topicId="{dlesScore>ID}" topic="{dlCourses>LJ_SOLUTION}" dles="{dlCourses>DLES}" id="tileDLESCourse" press=".handleCourseClick"></dles:DLESScoreTile>
        </tiles>
    </TileContainer>`
```

and on the backend on inint fucntion I'm trying to filter by `LJ_SOLUTION` but it doesn't work. it gives me all the courses. I'm getting LJ_SOLUTION from query string that's why i'm not filtring on front end. 
the code is as

```
        var coursePath = "/DLES_COURSE_CONTENT";
        var filterByName = new sap.ui.model.Filter('LJ_SOLUTION', 'EQ', 'Analytics')
        //sPath = "/DLES_SOLUTION_CONTENT?$filter=LJ_SOLUTION eq  '" + sId + "')";
        var courses = oView.getModel("dlCourses");
        var courseData = oModel.getData(coursePath);
        oView.bindElement({
            path: coursePath,
            filters: [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("LJ_SOLUTION",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "Analytics") ],
            model: "dlCourses",
            events: {
                dataRequested: function() {

                    oView.setBusy(true);
                },
                dataReceived: function() {
                    oView.setBusy(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

The network tab...
[image: DLES_COURSE_CONTENT REQUEST] 
there is another request batch I don't understand completely but the request query is as 
[image: batch Request Query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            var oView = this.getView();
var oSolutionJourneyList = oView.byId("idsolutionContainer");
            var oBinding = oSolutionJourneyList.getBinding("tiles");
            if (oBinding) {
                var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("LJ_SOLUTION", 'EQ', 'Analytics');
                oBinding.filter([oFilter]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the code `“var courseData = oModel.getData(coursePath);”`

because this loads the entire model.  The bindElement will also create a request to load the required data only. Then, check the request which is created by bindElement to see if the path for `“LJ_Solution”` is correct.

Comment: I've removed `var courseData = oModel.getData(coursePath);` and I'm sure the path which I'm giving for `LJ_Solution` is correct. It still loading whole data. Did you check my view code as well.

Comment: One more thing, How I can check my request. I've right request ? secondly what data i'm getting after req

Comment: on query string I've passed `/DLES_COURSE_CONTENT.xsodata/DLES_COURSE_CONTENT?$filter=LJ_SOLUTION eq 'Analytics'`  It gives me the right results.

Comment: Please check the request created by the bindElement in the network trace.

Then, you should see the oData request going to the backend with the filter and the data received as a result. Could you add the details to the blogß

Comment: I've updated the question with request url. I'm expecting one url with filter query string. but that is not present there.

Comment: the response of batch URL includes all the records. Not filtered one

Comment: I am new to SAPUI5, so may be everything i am doing here is wrong.

Comment: Please check the request created by the bindElement in the network trace.
Then, you should see the oData request going to the backend with the filter and the data received as a result. Could you please add the details to your question?